# Anchor /#anchor is printed in url like this /#/anchor/2

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, anchor

im using an href="./#anchor" in a navbar, and after klicking it, the page reloads, because there is a preloader used, and the url is printing out "website/#/anchor/2" instead of "website/#anchor"

even if i delete every javascript used (preloader included) this curiosity still appears.
There is also no base tag inside of the html document.
This appears on live & local server.

hope somebody can help,
thanks !